# declare(strict_types=1) что означает?

Tags: php

хотел бы узнать что делает declare(strict_types=1), мне сказали сюда идти за ответом

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict

Answer (score 0):

Включает строгую типизацию для файла в котором вызвана даная конструкция